# displaying images from sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am an android application developer. I am currently developing an application which requires of me to display an image stored in an sqlite database, Could anyone guide me on how to retrieve an image from a sqlite database and display it...
Thanks..

Comment: Loading images from a database, especially SQLite, is not a great idea. It can be very slow, so if you have many images will take a long to do what you want. The best thing to do is to store an image name or ID and then load the image from the project from this given ID. I haven't done this on Android yet, but have on iPhone and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I would begin with:

```
db.rawQuery('SELECT imageBlob FROM Images WHERE imageID=?', new String[] {imageID});
```

Then save the result to a file (for that bit, I don't know exactly, being new to Android and all).