# android tag an image with GPS location and save to database

Tags: android, gps, android-camera

1.i have written code to take an image by android phone
2. i got current location of the user
 Now i want to save this image in sqlite db along with current gps location So that one could view image in Map with its tagged details.

Please help. I am very new to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915775/storing-images-in-sqlite-android) can be used for storing the image as a blob file and retrieving it.

My advice would be like instead of saving the image to sqliteDB, better just save the path of the image. Directly saving in the sqliteDB will result in increase in the application memory usage. This way you can depend on SD card.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: but how to tag gps location with the image so that we can see that image in map.