# Android SQLite, a table with a colum of type View

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Can I make the items in a  table new objects I create, instead of a String or Integer.
This object is a View actually.
If I make no sense, here is what I want to do:
According to the first name and the last name entered, you get an Image(on a new window) specified in the SQL table as a new column(Image column) except the columns of first and last name.
If there is a way of doing it without SQL, please let me know.

If you know any tutorials talking about what I mentioned, please add them to your response.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XWam.png)

Comment: A `View` cannot be stored in persistent storage by any means (file, database, whatever). Instead, store the data that you use to know how to populate the `View`.

Comment: These are the datatypes you can use in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store an actual `View` object in your sqlite database. Your views should be reusable for different data rows in your application.

Going off of your image, you could do something like this:

`FragmentA` contains the 'First Name' and 'Last Name' view.

`FragmentB` contains the image and some text view.

Your data table could look something like this:

```
|  FirstName  |  LastName  |  ImageName  |  SomeText  |
|  Almog      |  Nita      |  img1.jpg   |  Text!!    |
|  Ruby       |  Nita      |  img2.jpg   |  Text2!!   |
|  Nisha      |  Nita      |  img3.jpg   |  Text3!    |
```

That way, you are able to reuse the `FragmentB` and decide what images you want to show based on the image name column in your database. If you do not want to store the image name and want to store an image blob, it's possible to do that. You should search stackoverflow for answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915775/storing-images-in-sqlite-android).